# Twitter API - Getting friends and follower ids for a set of users?

Tags: twitter

I am able to extract tweets, and the submitter's user details using the streaming API, but I also need the **list of followers and friends of users** posting these tweets.

I am aware that Twitter search API has the **friends/ids** and **followers/ids** functions through which one can get the public followers and friends list one user at a time.

But, my data collection requires getting this information for all the users whose tweets I have collected, around **20,000+ users**. This is quite exhaustive given the high number of users, and the limitation of one user per call. Moreover, I need to **refresh this list** for each of these 20,000+ users **preferably once a day** to observe changes in their friends and followers (if any).

IS there any I can achieve this using the Twitter Streaming API or any other method. Or I have to apply for the Twitter commercial data license?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

20,000 is way beyond the limits of any normal Twitter API method. I think your going to have to apply for a commercial license to go that high. The streaming API, I believe, tracks 400 keywords and 5000 users max. Your right in that the REST twitter API method only allows you to track one user or a list of ID's. You can take a look at the [Twitter Counter](http://www.twittercounter.com) API which mines additional info including information about followers, etc. But again, 20,000 I'm sure would be above the limits. Communicate with Twitter, [Gnip](http://www.gnip.com) and, and the Twitter Counter service to see what they can do for you.

Twitter Counter API:

http://twittercounter.com/pages/api?ref=footer